# Selecionando dados e organizando por intervalo de 15min Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, datetime, dateinterval

Boa tarde, tenho a seguinte query que me retorna a quantidade de veículos na via entre determinado horário . Porém quero pegar esse intervalo entre horários e montar intervalos entre 15min. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
@CodLocal int = 38,
@Data varchar(10) = '2019-05-16',
@HoraIni varchar(8) = '08:00:00',
@HoraFin varchar(8) = '09:00:00'
as


Select  M.* , "TotalEq"  = CASE NomTipo
    WHEN 'Motocicletas/Bicicletas'  THEN (Total*0.35)
    WHEN 'Automóveis'               THEN (Total*1)
    WHEN 'Caminhão/Ônibus'          THEN (Total*2)
    WHEN 'Caminhões 3 ou 4 Eixos'   THEN (Total*3)
    WHEN'Caminhões 5 ou mais Eixos' THEN (Total*4)
    END

 from
(


Select "HoraIni"  = @HoraIni, "HoraFin" = @HoraFin,  Data,  
"NomTipo" = case Tipo 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Motocicletas/Bicicletas'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Automóveis' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Caminhão/Ônibus'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Caminhões 3 ou 4 Eixos'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Caminhões 5 ou mais Eixos'

End, 
Lc.NomLocal, "Total" = count(*)   from TbColeta Cl
Join TbLocal Lc on Cl.CodLocal = Lc.CodLocal

where Cl.CodLocal = @CodLocal and Data = @Data and Hora Between @HoraIni and @HoraFin 
group by Data, Tipo, Lc.NomLocal
) M
```

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` utilizado?

Comment: Microsoft sql server management studio 2012

Comment: Se fosse no PostgreSQL você poderia utilizar a função generate_series (Set Returning Function). Não sei se existe algo parecido no Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: O exemplo mais próximo que encontrei foi esse (https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/group-data-into-15-minute-intervals)

Comment: Como estão declaradas as colunas Data e Hora? A qual tabela elas pertencem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou informar como estão declaradas as colunas.

```
-- código #1
@CodLocal int = 38,
@Data varchar(10) = '2019-05-16',
@HoraIni varchar(8) = '08:00:00',
@HoraFin varchar(8) = '09:00:00'
as

with 
Selecionado as (
SELECT Tipo, 
       (datediff (minute, 0, HORA) / 60) as H,
       --(datediff (minute, 0, HORA) % 60) as M,
       ((datediff (minute, 0, HORA) % 60) / 15) as G   
  from tbColeta  
  where CodLocal = @CodLocal 
        and Data = @Data 
        and Hora between @HoraIni and @HoraFin 
),
Agrupado as (
SELECT H, G, Tipo, count(*) as Qtd
  from Selecionado
  group by H, G, Tipo
)
SELECT @CodLocal as [Código do local],
       (SELECT top (1) NomLocal from tbLocal where CodLocal = @CodLocal) as [Nome local],
       @Data as Data,
       cast (dateadd (minute, (H * 60) + (G * 15), 0) as time(0)) as Inicio,
       cast (dateadd (second, (H * 3600) + ((G + 1) * 15 * 60 -1), 0) as time(0)) as Fim,
       case Tipo 
            when 1 then 'Motocicletas/Bicicletas'
            when 2 then 'Automóveis' 
            when 3 then 'Caminhão/Ônibus'
            when 4 then 'Caminhões 3 ou 4 Eixos'
            when 5 then 'Caminhões 5 ou mais Eixos' end as [Tipo de veículo],
       case Tipo 
            when 1 then Qtd * 0.35
            when 2 then Qtd 
            when 3 then Qtd * 2
            when 4 then Qtd * 3
            when 5 then Qtd * 4 end as TotalEq
  from Agrupado
  order by Inicio, Fim;
```

Na CTE `Selecionado`, o valor da coluna HORA é separado em horas, minutos e faixa de minutos (0, para 0 a 14; 1 para 15 a 29 etc).

Na CTE `Agrupado` é realizado o cálculo por cada faixa e tipo de veículo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma `CTE` com os intervalos possíveis dentro dos horários que você determinou e assim cruzar os dados que você já tem. Para os intervalos utilize a cláusula `WITH` da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @inicio DATETIME = '2019-05-16 08:00:00';
DECLARE @fim DATETIME = '2019-05-16 09:00:00';

WITH intervalos AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id,
         @inicio AS inicio,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @inicio) AS fim
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.id + 1 AS id,
         i.fim AS inicio,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, i.fim) AS fim
    FROM intervalos i
   WHERE i.fim < @fim
)
SELECT *
  FROM intervalos i
```

Que resultará no seguinte:

```
id  | inicio                  | fim
---------------------------------------------------
1   | 2019-05-16 08:00:00.000 | 2019-05-16 08:15:00.000
2   | 2019-05-16 08:15:00.000 | 2019-05-16 08:30:00.000
3   | 2019-05-16 08:30:00.000 | 2019-05-16 08:45:00.000
4   | 2019-05-16 08:45:00.000 | 2019-05-16 09:00:00.000
```

Com essa tabela você só precisará realizar um `JOIN`e terá o resultado desejado.

---

> [`WITH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> **APLICA-SE A:** `SQL Server` (a partir do 2008), `Banco de Dados SQL do Azure`, `SQL Data Warehouse do Azure` e `Parallel Data Warehouse`
>
> Especifica um conjunto de resultados nomeado temporário, conhecido como uma `CTE` (expressão de tabela comum). Ela é derivada de uma consulta simples e definida no escopo de execução de uma única instrução `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `MERGE`. Esta cláusula também pode ser usada em uma instrução CREATE VIEW como parte da instrução `SELECT` que a define. Uma expressão de tabela comum pode incluir referências a si mesma. É o que chamamos de expressão de tabela comum recursiva.
>
> [**Sintaxe**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)
>
> ```
> [ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]  
>
> <common_table_expression>::=  
> expression_name [ ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]  
> AS  
> ( CTE_query_definition )
> ```
>
> [**Argumentos**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)
>
> `expression_name`
>
> É um identificador válido para a expressão de tabela comum. `expression_name` deve ser diferente do nome de qualquer outra expressão de tabela comum definida na mesma cláusula `WITH <common_table_expression>`, mas `expression_name` pode ser o mesmo que o nome de uma tabela base ou exibição. Qualquer referência a `expression_name` na consulta usa a expressão de tabela comum, e não o objeto base.
>
> `column_name`
>
> Especifica um nome de coluna na expressão de tabela comum. Não são permitidos nomes duplicados em uma única definição de `CTE`. O número de nomes de coluna especificado deve corresponder ao número de colunas no conjunto de resultados da `CTE_query_definition`. A lista de nomes de colunas será opcional somente se forem fornecidos nomes distintos para todas as colunas resultantes na definição da consulta.
>
> `CTE_query_definition`
>
> Especifica uma instrução `SELECT` cujo conjunto de resultados popula a expressão de tabela comum. A instrução `SELECT` de `CTE_query_definition` deve atender aos mesmos requisitos da criação de uma exibição, com a exceção de que uma `CTE` não pode definir outra `CTE`. Para obter mais informações, consulte a seção Comentários e [`CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
>
> Se mais de uma `CTE_query_definition` for definida, as definições de consulta poderão ser unidas por um destes dois conjuntos de operadores: `UNION ALL`, `UNION`, `EXCEPT` ou `INTERSECT`.

Comment: Certo Sorack, vou fazer aqui e retorno com respostas.

Comment: Sorack, desta forma o horário inicial é sempre o mesmo. Eu queria que o final de um fosse o início do outro. Por exemplo: inicio 08:00 - final 08:14:59 / inicio 08:15:00 - final 08:29:59 ...

Comment: @ErickBessa você só precisa usar o `DATEADD(SECOND, -1, data)` na data final.